# Int type overflow in chr()

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

```
rsadecrypt::(Int,Int)->Int->[Char]
rsadecrypt (d,m) x = chr((x^d)`mod`m)
```

for example
if 'x' has the value 17 and 'd' has the value 91, then x^d should be 17^91 = 9.350866e+111.
But this only applies to Integer type,you will get a wrong answer with Int type.

Integer type
17^91 = 9.350866e+111

Int type
17^91 = wrong answer, overflow.

Int type will give a negative number, which is wrong(overflow).

The problem is, I cannot use Integer for chr(),Only Int is approved.

How can I solve this problem? pls help me . I'm newbie =-+"

Comment: You can calculate a "powerMod", so a function that calculates `a^b mod c`, and keeps it all in the `Int` type.

Answer (score 3):

Options include, in roughly increasing order of desirability:

1. Do the exponentiation in `Integer` then convert back to `Int` after the `mod` operation. Use `toInteger :: Int -> Integer` and `fromInteger :: Integer -> Int` for the conversions.
2. Write your own exponentiation operation that reduces mod `m` after each multiplication.
3. Use [`Mod`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/arithmoi-0.11.0.1/docs/Math-NumberTheory-Moduli-Class.html#t:Mod), or, if `m` must be chosen dynamically and cannot be statically known, [`SomeMod`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/arithmoi-0.11.0.1/docs/Math-NumberTheory-Moduli-Class.html#t:SomeMod), for which `(^)` does reduction after each multiplication already. Use `fromIntegral :: KnownNat m => Int -> Mod m` and `fromInteger . getVal :: Mod m -> Int` or `(fromInteger .) . modulo :: Integer -> Natural -> SomeMod` and pattern matching for conversions.

Comment: Thx, it works. `chr(fromInteger(x^d`mod`m) :: Int)`